# How to read a counter key value pair from python in R?

Tags: r

I have data generated from a Python script where the entries look like:

```
Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 2})
```

or

```
Counter({'a': 4, 'b': 1, 'c': 7})
```

If the above are read as characters in R, how can I extract the values into a single vector or other object that R can read? So, in the second example, we would have:

```
c('a','a','a','a','b','c','c','c','c','c','c','c')
```

Comment: So do you want to recreate a python parser in R? Or do you want to run python code in R? Or are you string parse this and only this very specific call to Counter that happens to be in a string for some reason? You can expand that vector in R with `rep(c("a","b","c"), c(4,1,7))` but the parsing part will not be pretty.

Comment: Have you tried this yet? https://gist.github.com/erinshellman/7405574 . Not sure it's exactly what you need but it might help with regexp ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's close enough to json that I think we can use `jsonlite` to help:

```r
S <- "Counter({'a': 4, 'b': 1, 'c': 7})"
gsub("'", '"', gsub("^Counter\\(|\\)$", "", S))
# [1] "{\"a\": 4, \"b\": 1, \"c\": 7}"
S2 <- jsonlite::fromJSON(gsub("'", '"', gsub("^Counter\\(|\\)$", "", S)))
S2
# $a
# [1] 4
# $b
# [1] 1
# $c
# [1] 7
rep(names(S2), times = unlist(S2))
#  [1] "a" "a" "a" "a" "b" "c" "c" "c" "c" "c" "c" "c"
```